# Python 'Path' module's 'mkdir()' creates a directory with a name from memory?

Tags: python, zip

Below is the code for

- unzipping a folder containing text fies
- find and replace a string within those file
- zip it back.

```
import shutil
import zipfile
import sys
from pathlib import Path
        
class ZipProcessor:
    def __init__(self, zipname):
        self.zipname = zipname
        self.temp_directory = Path("unzipped-{}".format(zipname[:-4]))

    def process_zip(self):
        self.unzip_files()
        self.process_files()
        self.zip_files()

    def unzip_files(self):
        self.temp_directory.mkdir()
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.zipname) as zip: 
            zip.extractall(str(self.temp_directory))

    def zip_files(self):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.zipname, 'w') as file:
            for filename in self.temp_directory.iterdir():
                print(filename)                            # second
                file.write(str(filename), filename.name)
        shutil.rmtree(str(self.temp_directory))


class ZipReplace(ZipProcessor):
    def __init__(self, filename, search_string,replace_string):
        super().__init__(filename)
        self.search_string = search_string
        self.replace_string = replace_string
    
    def process_files(self):
        '''perform a search and replace on all files in the
        temporary directory'''
        for filename in self.temp_directory.iterdir():
            with filename.open() as file:
                contents = file.read()
            contents = contents.replace(self.search_string, self.replace_string)
            with filename.open("w") as file:
                file.write(contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZipReplace(*sys.argv[1:4]).process_zip()
```

I run the code with the `python3 EX5_zip.py replace3.zip 'code' 'program'`

The error is receive is `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'unzipped-replace3/replace'`

My doubt is regarding the directory `replace` under the temp_directory path. How did it get created with that name? I doubt if its from the previous run of the script [ I had given zipfile as ```replace.zip``]. if that's the case how do I remove it from the memory ?

I used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python) to remove memory but the it remains.

Comment: It's not in memory, it's in your filesystem. You can remove it with the `rm` command.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- there was already a `replace` subfolder in `unzipped-replace3`
- or there is a `replace` directory *inside* your `replace3.zip` zip file so that folder was created by `extractall`

So when you try to open the `Path("replace")` given by `iterdir` with `filename.open`, it fails. You should first test if `filename` is a directory or not with `filename.is_dir()`.